# Add on click event instead of hover on magento menu

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1, magento2.4.2, magento2.4.3, magento2.4.2-p1

I want to add an on-click event on the menu instead of hover in Magento Luma Theme.
I have checked a lot of solutions but nothing is properly understandable.
Can someone help me out on the same?

Thanks,
Rashi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution i.e. by overriding menu.js file at location app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/web/mage/menu.js

Modified the function _toggleDesktopMode -
Function will look like

```
_toggleDesktopMode: function () {
        var categoryParent, html;

        $(this.element).off('click mousedown mouseenter mouseleave');

        this._on({

            /**
             * Prevent focus from sticking to links inside menu after clicking
             * them (focus should always stay on UL during navigation).
             */
            'mousedown .ui-menu-item > a': function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
            },

            /**
             * Prevent focus from sticking to links inside menu after clicking
             * them (focus should always stay on UL during navigation).
             */
            'click .ui-state-disabled > a': function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
            },

            /**
             * @param {jQuer.Event} event
             */
            'click .ui-menu-item:has(a)': function (event) {
                if ($(event.target).siblings('.submenu').length || $(event.target).parent().siblings('.submenu').length) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    var target = $(event.target).closest('.ui-menu-item');

                    if (!this.mouseHandled && target.not('.ui-state-disabled').length) {
                        this.select(event);

                        // Open submenu on click
                        if (target.has('.ui-menu').length) {
                            this.expand(event);
                        } else if (!this.element.is(':focus') &&
                            $(this.document[0].activeElement).closest('.ui-menu').length
                        ) {
                            // Redirect focus to the menu
                            this.element.trigger('focus', [true]);

                            // If the active item is on the top level, let it stay active.
                            // Otherwise, blur the active item since it is no longer visible.
                            if (this.active && this.active.parents('.ui-menu').length === 1) { //eslint-disable-line
                                clearTimeout(this.timer);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },

            /**
             * @param {jQuery.Event} event
             */
            'click .ui-menu-item': function (event) {

                var target = $(event.currentTarget),
                    submenu = this.options.menus,
                    ulElement,
                    ulElementWidth,
                    width,
                    targetPageX,
                    rightBound;

                if (target.has(submenu)) {
                    ulElement = target.find(submenu);
                    ulElementWidth = ulElement.outerWidth(true);
                    width = target.outerWidth() * 2;
                    targetPageX = target.offset().left;
                    rightBound = $(window).width();

                    if (ulElementWidth + width + targetPageX > rightBound) {
                        ulElement.addClass('submenu-reverse');
                    }

                    if (targetPageX - ulElementWidth < 0) {
                        ulElement.removeClass('submenu-reverse');
                    }
                }

                // Remove ui-state-active class from siblings of the newly focused menu item
                // to avoid a jump caused by adjacent elements both having a class with a border
                target.siblings().children('.ui-state-active').removeClass('ui-state-active');
                this.focus(event, target);
            },
            /**
             * @param {jQuery.Event} event
             */
            'mouseleave': function (event) {
                this.collapseAll(event, true);
            },

            /**
             * Mouse leave.
             */
        });

        categoryParent = this.element.find('.all-category');
        html = $('html');

        categoryParent.remove();

        if (html.hasClass('nav-open')) {
            html.removeClass('nav-open');
            setTimeout(function () {
                html.removeClass('nav-before-open');
            }, this.options.hideDelay);
        }
    },
```

This is working perfectly fine according to my requirement.

Thanks,
Rashi